# chaining an I/O bound and a cpu bound operation in python multtprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I want to fetch/read data from the filesystem and then process them with some number crunching function. The former is an io bound hence I will benefit by running multiple threads on it (using `multiprocessing.dummy.pool` and `pool.map`) whereas the latter being cpu bound will benefit by multiple processes (using `multiprocessing.pool` and `pool.map`).

How can I chain those two please, is this doable? Or the only way is to do them sequentially, ie parse all the flatfiles from the disk using multithreading and when this is finished do the calculations using multiprocessing by feeding-in the data that the multitreading step has produced.

Comment: You could collect the results from the thread pool and dump them into the multiprocessing pool (e.g. via [`concurrent.futures.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/concurrent.futures.html) or set up a multi-producer/multi-consumer queue between a group of threads and a group of processes. The thing to look out for is what happens if the IO is faster than the computation? You could run out of memory when you load too much data at once

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give a precise answer, which depends on how the I/O-bound and CPU-bound computations are related, but this should give you a general idea. Essentially you want to pass to your I/O-bound worker function a multiprocessing pool instance to be used for the CPU-bound calculations.

Note that this is not meant to be a realistic example since function `cpu_bound_computation` is not actually CPU-intensive.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
import requests
from functools import partial

def cpu_bound_computation(text):
    # Peform calculations on text:
    ...
    return len(text)

def io_bound_work(multiprocessing_pool, url):
    # Get some result text from some website:
    resp = requests.get(url)
    text = resp.text
    # Yes! A blocking call since we have nothing to return
    # until we get the result of our CPU-bound computation:
    l = multiprocessing_pool.apply(cpu_bound_computation, (text,))
    return l

def main():
    list_of_urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://bing.com']
    with Pool() as multiprocessing_pool, \
    ThreadPool(len(list_of_urls)) as thread_pool:
        worker = partial(io_bound_work, multiprocessing_pool)
        results = thread_pool.map(worker, list_of_urls)
        print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
[19283, 45092]
```